# Can concurrent write access to the same object from asynchronous functions cause invalid values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I wonder if the following code can cause the integer `i` in the object `context` to have an invalid value. So far, I could not cause a problem in my experiments.

```
// Node.js (v10.19.0)

const Promise = require('promise')

// object accessed from different async processes in parallel
let context = {i: 0}

// create async functions
let funkMaker = function(i) { 
  return async function(context) { 
    context.i += 1; 
    console.log(`Funk${i} at ${Date.now()}: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: ${context.i}`); 
    return context.i 
  } 
}

// create async processes
let funksArr = []; 
for (k=1; k<101; k++) { 
  funksArr.push(funkMaker(k)) 
}

// invoke async processes in parallel
Promise.all(
  funksArr.map(f => f(context))
).then(
  x => console.log(`Promise.all resolved with ${x}`)
).catch(
  e => console.log(`Promise.all raised an error:\n${e}`)
)
```

The above produces the following output (excerpt):

```
Funk1 at 1584448782621: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: 1   
Funk2 at 1584448782621: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: 2   
Funk3 at 1584448782622: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: 3   
Funk4 at 1584448782622: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: 4   
Funk5 at 1584448782622: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: 5   
Funk6 at 1584448782622: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: 6   
Funk7 at 1584448782622: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: 7    
Funk8 at 1584448782622: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: 8  
Funk9 at 1584448782622: Incremented argument 'context.i' to: 9
```

As you can see there are several processes that appear to be accessing `context.i` at the very same millisecond (`Funk3` to `Funk9` above). I am puzzled as to why the integer `context.i` still gets incremented correctly and without an error.

Insights are most welcome. Thank you!

**UPDATE**

In order to try this out in true system threads I adjusted code stolen from [this blog post](https://medium.com/better-programming/is-node-js-really-single-threaded-7ea59bcc8d64) which uses `crypto` and implicitly `libuv` to have execution in real threads. I still could not get my `context.i` get to break. And I still am puzzled, to be honest.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const start = Date.now();

let context = {i: 0}

function logHashTime(context) {
  crypto.pbkdf2("a", "b", 100000, 512, "sha512", () => {
    context.i += 1;
    console.log(`Hash: ${Date.now() - start}, 'context.i' incremented to: ${context.i}`);
  });
}

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  logHashTime(context)
}
```

The output (excerpt) still is "fine":

```
Hash: 1268, 'context.i' incremented to: 1  
Hash: 1460, 'context.i' incremented to: 2  
Hash: 1660, 'context.i' incremented to: 3  
Hash: 1907, 'context.i' incremented to: 4  
Hash: 2493, 'context.i' incremented to: 5  
Hash: 2673, 'context.i' incremented to: 6  
Hash: 3154, 'context.i' incremented to: 7  
Hash: 3215, 'context.i' incremented to: 8  
Hash: 3662, 'context.i' incremented to: 9
```

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, so unless you increment `i` in some other `async` method, then it won't increment out of sync.  eg. if you had `context.i += 1; await delay(100);`,  `context.i` would be all over the place.. :)

Comment: Thank you @Keith for the quick and insightful reply. Unfortunately I am still unsure if I understood your answer in depth. So, how could I make this fail, i.e. cause `context.i` to be all over the place, as you say? Cheers

Comment: @Keith `context.i += 1; await delay(100);` is still totally fine. Problematic code would look like `const temp = context.i; await delay(100); context.i = temp+1;`

Comment: @Bergi It's still not fine, all the resolved values will be wrong.. :)  In fact they will all be 100.. :)  IOW: this -> `console.log(`Promise.all resolved with ${x}`)`  would output `100,100,100,100..........`

Comment: Hi @Bergi and @Keith! I just tested the snippet `context.i += 1; await delay(100); return context.i` and I have to say @Keith is right. The `console.log` returns values that are as expected, and more importantly I never saw illegal values in `context.i`, but the promises all resolve to `100,100,100,...`. However, I actually am not really interested in the resolve values. I just want to know, if I can "break" `context.i` by concurrent access to it?

Comment: Following up on my above comment: You can of course solve the issue with the `100,100,100,...` with the following snippet `let i = context.i += 1; await delay(100); return i` Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

First off, you have no actual asynchronous code here.  While your function is declared `async`, it's function body still executes synchronously and there are no actual asynchronous operations in that body.  The fact that it is tagged as `async` means it returns a promise, but that's all that changes in your example.

Second, Javascript runs your Javascript in a single thread unless you explicitly use Worker Threads (which you are not using there).

So, since everything is synchronous and it's all run in a single thread, the code just runs reliably in the order your `.map()` loop runs.  The only thing here that is actually asynchronous is when the promises returned by the `async` function call their `.then()` handler which allows `Promise.all()` to call its `.then()` handler.  But, all the results were generated synchronously before that.

> As you can see there are several processes that appear to be accessing context.i at the very same millisecond (Funk3 to Funk9 above). I am puzzled as to why the integer context.i still gets incremented correctly and without an error.

They are all run one at a time, in order.  You see the same millisecond only because you don't have enough timer resolution to actually see the difference in time of execution.  None of the functions are actually running "at the same time".

`context.i` gets incremented correctly because the functions are actually called and run one after another, in order.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00! That helped a lot. Of course, you are right, using `async` functions does not do the trick. I looked at [this post](https://medium.com/better-programming/is-node-js-really-single-threaded-7ea59bcc8d64) and tried something similar with `crypto`, which supposedly causes execution in true threads with `libuv`. I still got the same result. So, can I break my `context.i` or can't I? If not, I can go ahead and use it in my code, which by the way does have asynchronous database executions... Thanks

Comment: @user3139868 - It really depends upon what your real code is doing.  You can't prove anything with a made-up example that is different than your real code.  If you want a real answer, you will have to show your real code so we can see what you're actually doing.  Actual asynchronous callbacks or actual asynchronous operations that return a promise will finish in an unpredictable order so you cannot make any assumptions about the order in which they will complete unless you force an execution order by how you write the code.

Comment: Thank you @user3139868. Sadly we do not have code to share, cause we're thinking about a design before implementing it. Goal is to provide a maximum number of records that can be fetched in a GraphQL-server. If you have a simple schema like a Person has Dogs and also has Parrots, GraphQL resolves queries to a Person, the associated Dogs and associated Parrots, separately, but the last two ones in parallel. The idea is to put in `context.i` the number of already fetched records. Each resolver diminishes it according to the fetched records and errors if exceeded. Can this break `context.i`?

Comment: @user3139868 - Still not enough to go on.  It totally depends upon how the code is written.  It is possible to write correct code that has multiple asynchronous operations running in parallel that each want to operate on some shared data (that's what `Promise.all()` does internally to count when all the requests are done).  It is also possible to mess it up based on how you write the code by making copies of variables and using those copies that become static rather than live.